# Why jQuery unobtrusive validation is triggered by default for file inputs even without any scripts on the page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I'm using Razor Pages and also the data annotation attributes on my page model's properties like this:

```
public class AddModel : PageModel
{
    ...

    [DisplayName("عکس اصلی محصول")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    [ImageFile(ErrorMessage = "عکس اصلی محصول نامعتبر است")]
    public IFormFile MainImage { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("عکس های گالری محصول")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    [ListNotEmpty(ErrorMessage = "لطفا عکس های گالری محصول را وارد کنید")]
    [ImageFile(ErrorMessage = "عکس های گالری محصول نامعتبر هستند")]
    [ListMaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "عکس های گالری محصول نمی‌تواند بیشتر از 10 عدد باشد")]
    public List<IFormFile> GalleryImages { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Some of these attributes are custom, and I also made their client side version and added them to jquery's validation methods, and they work fine but the validation errors on file inputs just won't go away.

This is the main layout and I commented all the scripts:

[image]

And then on the page, the errors are still there!!! (those two red inputs are the `IFormFile` and `List<IFormFile>` on my page's model):

[image]

And because there is no validation scripts, the form can be submited although other inputs were required, but the errors under the file inputs won't go away.
I seriously don't know what is going on. Is this the default behavior?

Comment: Instead of putting the picture, put the code of the whole form

Comment: if you check the ```ModelState.IsValid``` on the controller action that should allow you to check the model is valid before submission, as for the validation that won't go away is that the jquery validation or your custom data annotation validation?

Comment: There's no jquery validation on the page since all the script tags are commented, I think the data annotations need those scripts to render the errors, but in the picture, even without any scripts, the errors are there by default, but if I submit the form, other input's error won't show up, because as I said, there's no script on the page. But those two inputs have errors all the time.

Comment: I suggest you could also check your application to check if you have call the _ValidationScriptsPartial inside this partial view, it contains the validation required jquery scripts reference.

Comment: No, I haven't used any partial views that might be calling the `_ValidationScriptsPartial` partial view. I even commented the script tags inside `_ValidationScriptsPartial` and even the main code in the `jquery.unobtrusive.min.js` and `jquery.validate.min.js`, but it's still showing the errors!

Comment: To check if you have reference the jquery.unobtrusive.min.js, you could directly open the page and use F12 to see if the network sends the request to get the  jquery.unobtrusive.min.js.

Comment: No, there's no `jquery.unobtrusive.min.js` in the network tab as well. I think this might be the default behavior, but I'm curious to know how it shows those errors without any jquery validation scripts, but I think I'm just going to deal with it, with an additional downvote that I'll never know why I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda unexpected, but this is how it got solved, when I posted the question, my page's model contained the properties with data annotations directly in it, like this:

```
[BindProperties]
public class AddModel : BaseRazorPage
{    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.IdRequired)]
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "نام محصول")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.ProductNameRequired)]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "نام انگلیسی محصول")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    public string? EnglishName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("اسلاگ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.SlugRequired)]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("توضیحات")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.DescriptionRequired)]
    [MaxLength(2000, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("عکس اصلی محصول")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    [ImageFile(ErrorMessage = "عکس اصلی محصول نامعتبر است")]
    public IFormFile MainImage { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("عکس های گالری محصول")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    [ListNotEmpty(ErrorMessage = "لطفا عکس های گالری محصول را وارد کنید")]
    [ImageFile(ErrorMessage = "عکس های گالری محصول نامعتبر هستند")]
    [ListMaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "عکس های گالری محصول نمی‌تواند بیشتر از 10 عدد باشد")]
    public List<IFormFile> GalleryImages { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("مشخصات")]
    public List<SpecificationViewModel>? CustomSpecifications { get; set; } = new() { new() };

    [DisplayName("توضیحات اضافه")]
    [DictionaryMembersCharactersMaxLength(100, 2000, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    public Dictionary<string, string>? ExtraDescriptions { get; set; } = new() { { "", "" } };

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

But then I extracted these properties into a separate view model class, like this:

```
public class CreateProductViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.IdRequired)]
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "نام محصول")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.ProductNameRequired)]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "نام انگلیسی محصول")]
    [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    public string? EnglishName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("اسلاگ")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.SlugRequired)]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("توضیحات")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.DescriptionRequired)]
    [MaxLength(2000, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("عکس اصلی محصول")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    [ImageFile(ErrorMessage = "عکس اصلی محصول نامعتبر است")]
    public IFormFile MainImage { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("عکس های گالری محصول")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا {0} را وارد کنید")]
    [ListNotEmpty(ErrorMessage = "لطفا عکس های گالری محصول را وارد کنید")]
    [ImageFile(ErrorMessage = "عکس های گالری محصول نامعتبر هستند")]
    [ListMaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "عکس های گالری محصول نمی‌تواند بیشتر از 10 عدد باشد")]
    public List<IFormFile> GalleryImages { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("مشخصات")]
    public List<ProductSpecificationViewModel>? Specifications { get; set; } = new() { new() };

    [DisplayName("توضیحات اضافه")]
    [DictionaryMembersCharactersMaxLength(100, 2000, ErrorMessage = ValidationMessages.MaxCharactersLength)]
    public Dictionary<string, string>? ExtraDescriptions { get; set; } = new() { { "", "" } };
}
```

And now my page model has only one single property which references that view model:

```
[BindProperties]
public class AddModel : BaseRazorPage
{
    public CreateProductViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```

And the errors of those two inputs no longer appear on the page load:

[image]

But work fine on submitting:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Since the property on my page model was a complex type, it couldn't bind the Lists inside the view model, so I had to new up an instance for its default value:

```
[BindProperties]
public class AddModel : BaseRazorPage
{                                                            
    public CreateProductViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new();
    
    public void OnGet()
    {
    }
}
```